# cURL to OWA not working from newly-installed RHEL server but working from Ubuntu server

Tags: exchange, haproxy, rhel8

I have two Linux servers acting as a reverse proxy between my Exchange server and the internet. The newest server is RHEL 8.7.

When I attempt to cURL to OWA from the RHEL server I am getting the following response:

```
<html><body><h1>503 Service Unavailable</h1>
No server is available to handle this request.
</body></html>
```

When I attempt the same request from the Ubuntu server, I get the HTML I'm expecting from OWA.

So far the troubleshooting I've done is as follows:

1. Both Linux servers are on the same network.
2. I've tried disabling the firewall on the Exchange server, but that made no difference.
3. I've tried enabling ALL traffic between the vLANs, but that made no difference.
4. I've tried disabling firewall rules on the RHEL server, but that made no difference.

I'm at a complete loss as to what else I can do to troubleshoot. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep in mind that RHEL does not use the last versions on many of its packages. But it comes with other advantages...

For example, HAProxy version:

- Ubuntu 22.x → HAProxy 2.4.x
- RHEL 8.7 → HAProxy 1.8.x

Comment: I think you're on to something here. I'm not familiar with the feature differences between HAProxy 2.x and 1.8.x; but the version difference is the only sensible explanation since the configuration is exactly the same. Thank you, although I am open to hear other people's comments in case someone else has been able to get this working.